# How to remove a specific element in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array as follows:

```
[[[Statistics (pH),  Upright, Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [Clearance pH  :  Channel 7], [Minimum,  2.42, 4.69, 2.42], [Maximum,  7.88, 7.51, 7.88], [Mean,  6.33, 6.41, 6.37], [Median,  6.62, 6.40, 6.49], [Standard Deviation,  0.91, 0.40, 0.73], [Variance,  0.84, 0.16, 0.54], [Gastric pH  :  Channel 8], [Minimum,  0.64, 0.57, 0.57], [Maximum,  7.86, 6.65, 7.86], [Mean,  2.12, 1.63, 1.93], [Median,  1.65, 1.24, 1.52], [Standard Deviation,  1.36, 0.99, 1.25], [Variance,  1.85, 0.99, 1.57]]]
```

I want to remove the elements `"Upright", "Recumbent", "Total"` from `[Statistics (pH),  Upright, Recumbent, Total]`

This is my code:

```
 for (ArrayList<List<String>> row : StatspH) {
     System.out.println(row);
     for (List<String> rowInner : row){
         rowInner.remove(0);
         System.out.println(rowInner);
     }
 }
```

This removes all the first elements in the inner array whereas I just want as above.. How can I specify where to remove it from?

Answer (score 0):

OK . Turns out it was as simple as

```
 for (ArrayList<List<String>> row2 : StatspH) {
      row2.get(0).remove(1);
     System.out.println("Result: " + row2);
 }
```